# десериализация yaml

Tags: c#, yaml, десериализация

При десериализации yaml файла выдает ошибку :
MissingMethodException: Для данного объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов.

```
 var yamlDeserializer = new Deserializer();
 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
 return;
 // получаем выбранный файл
 string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
 // читаем файл в строку
 Obertka list = yamlDeserializer.Deserialize<Obertka>
(File.ReadAllText(filename));
 dl.SetStudents(list.students);
 dl.SetGroups(list.groups);
 dl.SetFacult(list.faculty);
 MessageBox.Show("Export выполнен успешно");
```

Comment: И? Конструктор без параметров добавляли?

Comment: у Обертки добавлял!

Comment: У всех десериализуемых классов должен быть конструктор без параметров

Comment: Теперь новая ошибка :While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key."

Comment: yaml может плохо реагировать на пробелы, но это как вариант, сложно сказать что конкретно ему не нравится.